# How to test production build of Rails project with same Rpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rspec, bundler

I'm building an JSON API service with Rails and using docker for running it in production. In my Dockerfile I would want to use:

```
RUN bundle install --without development test
```

The thing I'm a bit worried is that the Gemfile might contain something really essential in `:development` or `:test`.

Here's an contrived example `Gemfile`:

```
# Example situation which works in development and tests but fails in production
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
end
```

In this case Tests would be passing just fine but production would be really broken.

So I was thinking of building the production container and running it with docker and exposing the port for testing. It would be awesome to use the same Rspec `type: request` tests against that container. Test runner and rails server can share the same test database.

How could I force my Rspec tests not to spawn their own server but to use a different service which is already running in background?

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is to build my docker container, then run it, wait 10 seconds, then grep the logs for your application server's success messages.

Usually grepping for the success message is far enough - you could do a simple smoke test, but then you're going down the road of canary deploys (which is fine, it's just a different mindset...)